# Linear conjugate of a cubic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

In any polynomial ring (but especially $K[x]$, $K$ number field) Is it true that for any cubic polynomial $p(x)$ there exist a linear polynomial $l(x)$ such that $l\circ p\circ l^{-1}=x^3+c$ for some constant $c\in K$?

We know it exists for quadratic polynomials but i wonder it exists for cubics or not.

Thank you.

Comment: If that were true the solution of cubics would not require square roots

Comment: @lhf:  In principle $l$ might require some square roots. Not that it exists...

Comment: @orangeskid, I had assumed that $l \in K[x]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{gae}[1]{\newcommand{#1}{\operatorname{#1}}}\gae{Frac}$No. For instance, that is impossible (at least, in domains) for polynomials in the form $(x-a)^2(x-b)$ with $a\ne b$.

*Added:* This is due to the fact that, if such an affine map existed, then your polynomial would have the same number of distinct roots in $\Frac K$ as $x^3+c-l(0)$. However, $x^3+\alpha$ may only have $0$, $1$ or $3$ distinct roots in the field $\Frac K$.

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: Yes yes you are right i couldnt see this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If such an $l$ exists then $p(x) = a (x+b)^3 + c$, for some $a$, $b$, $c\in \mathbb{C}$, $a\ne 0$. That means $p'(x)$ has a double root $-b$. That is almost never the case.

However, it is possible to write $p$ as the sum of two cubes of linear functions.